Trend test for multinomial variables
Which test should be used to estimate a p-value for trend when the outcome (dependent) variable is multinomial (with multiple unordered categories like race) and the independent variable is an ordered categorical variable say BMI with 3 categories (say <30 kg/m2, 30-40, >=40). And, how do you implement it in SAS and/or R. Any example code/reference would be helpful.
I believe we can use the Jonckheere–Terpstra trend test for continuous variables and Cochran–Armitage trend test for binary variables. But, I am not sure what the appropriate test is when it comes to multinomial variables.

I admittedly don't do a lot of multinomial analysis, but; what do you mean by "trend" when the outcome is an un-ordered categorical variable?

When you say trend, are you looking for a linear trend, a monotonic trend, or something else?

linear trend (apologies for not being clear)

I suggest multinomial logistic regression e.g. https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/ (there may be newer packages/methods). Basically, this fits a set of logistic regression models for the odds of response level $i$ against some arbitrary baseline $j$ (often $j$ is the most common category, or some theoretically useful baseline level). You can look for statistical significance of the coefficient of interest (e.g. BMI) just like you would for any GLM

If you can get your hands on "Categorical Data Analysis" book by Agresti, the section on multinomial responses is great

I am still not entirely sure what you mean by "trend" in your context, but it has a meaning in my above comments (relating to the odds of being category $i$ over category $j$)

@AlexJ: I think your suggestion about using multinomial logistic regression is correct.
